# how to delete duplicated rows in db2 when all the fields are duplicated?

Tags: db2, duplicates

I have a table:

```
 A
 1
 1
 1
 2
```

And I want to be transformed to

```
 A
 1
 2
```

How I might do it?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to delete directly by using the ROW_NUMBER [OLAP function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011043.html) to number the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS RN
    FROM my_table
)
WHERE RN > 1
```

I relied on [this discussion](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/DB2/Q_26333301.html) while writing the above.